# EF7 Scaffolding not creating columns

Tags: entity-framework, database-migration, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-migrations

I have a model that looks like this:

```
public class Order
{
    // removed irrelevant other properties
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public Address BuyerAddress { get; set; }
    public Address SellerAddress { get; set; }
}

public class Address
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Street { get; set; }
    public Order Order { get; set; }
}
```

In the DbContext I hooked them up like this:

```
entityTypeBuilder.HasOne(x => x.BuyerAddress).WithOne(x => x.Order).IsRequired(false);
entityTypeBuilder.HasOne(x => x.SellerAddress).WithOne(x => x.Order).IsRequired(false);
```

When I run

```
dnx ef migrations add Foo
dnx ef database update
```

The table is being created with some of the properties, but other properties, like the `SellerAddress` are missing (the `BuyerAddress` is being created fine though).

The same problem for other entities, such as `User` <-> `BankAccount` which is a 1:1 relationship that is defined as `entityTypeBuilder.HasOne(x => x.BankAccount).WithOne(x => x.User).IsRequired(false);`

Does anyone know what's up? I'm using Entity Framework 7.0.0-rc1-final. The issue is driving me crazy.

Comment: Look at the migration script in your Migrations folder, see what it's doing...

Comment: @NovaDev I did, and it just confirms that it's not creating the columns. I want to know why though. I need EF to generate the migrations correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed the problem. First I had foreign key properties, so my models looked like this:

```
public Order Order {get;set;}
public Guid OrderId {get;set;}
```

I didn't like this, and it resulted in duplicate columns in the database, so I removed the [EntityName]Id properties from my model. But because of this, EF got all confused could not longer figure out what I was trying to do. So for all 1:1 relationships I simply removed the navigation property on one side of the equation (so now Order has a reference to an Address, but Address no longer has a navigation property back to Order). This solved the problem.

So in case of the sample code in my question, I removed the `Order` property from `Address`.